# Representation of symmetry group $D_4$ acting on a square

Tags: group-theory, permutations, representation-theory, dihedral-groups, irreducible-representation

> Consider the square with vertices $(\pm 1, \pm 1)$. The symmetry group $D_4$ of this square acts by permuting the vertices
>
> 1. Show that each permutation comes from a linear transformation. Compute the trace of this representation.
> 2. Show that it is irreducible.

By *comes from a linear transformation*, does the question only demand that I argue that any action of $D_4$ is a combination of rotations and reflections and hence linear? Or, is there something else that the phrase *comes from* is supposed to mean?

Also, how do we compute the representation? What is the vector space corresponding to which we need to find the representation?

Comment: In order, the answers to your questions are "yes", "no", and "by choosing a basis, just like any question about how to compute some linear transformation quantity via matrices"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disclaimer 1: In the mathematical field of representation theory, group representations describe abstract groups in terms of **bijective linear transformations of a vector space to itself** (i.e. vector space automorphisms); in particular, they can be used to represent group elements as **invertible matrices** so that the group operation can be represented by matrix multiplication.

---

Disclaimer 2: A representation of a group G on a vector space V over a field K is a **group homomorphism from G to GL(V)**, (called the general linear group on V). That is, a representation is a map

$\rho \colon G\to \mathrm {GL} \left(V\right)$ such that
$\rho (g_{1}g_{2})=\rho (g_{1})\rho (g_{2}),\qquad {\text{for all }}g_{1},g_{2}\in G.$

In the case at hand, where V is of finite dimension $n$, it is common to **choose** a basis for $V$ and identify $GL(V)$ with $GL(n, K)$, the so called **group of n-by-n invertible matrices on the field K**. Thus

$\rho \colon G\to \mathrm {GL} \left(n,K\right)$, i e. the matrix representation.

One can show there exist hom(e)omorphisms $\phi:G\to\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb R)$ which map $s$ to each of your matrices $s_s$ and $r$ to each of your matrices $r_r$, and one can verify that the eight matrices $s_s$ and $r_r$ (see below) satisfy the same relations as the generators $s$ and $r$.

---

Invertible matrices for rotation and reflection of regular $n$-gons:
Let $r_{k}$ be the rotation around $(0,0)$ of angle $\alpha_{k}:=\frac{k\cdot 2\pi}{n}$

and $s_{k}$ the reflection across the line throught $(0,0)$ angled $\frac{\alpha_{k}}{2}=\frac{k\cdot \pi}{n}$ against the positive x-axis.

You then have, for $n$-gon in general:

$$r_{k}=\begin{pmatrix}\cos(\alpha _{k})&-\sin(\alpha _{k})\\\sin(\alpha _{k})&\cos(\alpha _{k})\end{pmatrix}$$

$$s_{k}=\begin{pmatrix}\cos(\alpha _{k})&\sin(\alpha _{k})\\\sin(\alpha _{k})&-\cos(\alpha _{k})\end{pmatrix}$$

---

The group (re)presentation of such a Dihedral group $D_n$ is:

$D_n=⟨α,β:α^n=β^2=e,βαβ=α^{−1}⟩$

The group presentation of the Dihedral group $D_4$ is thus given by:

$D_4=⟨a,b:a^4=b^2=e,bab=a^{−1}⟩$

Alternatively, with $r,s$ from above, our Dihedral group $D_4$ has the group presentation:

$D_4=⟨r,s:r^4=s^2=e,srs=r^{−1}⟩$

That is, the dihedral group $D_4$ is generated by two elements $r$ (rotation) and $s$ (reflection) such that:

$(1):r^4=e$
$(2):s^2=e$
$(3):sr=r^{3}s$ which is $srs=r^{-1}$.

---

The eight elements (read: linear transformations) of the Dihedral group $D_{4}$ in matrix form then are:

\begin{aligned}r_{0}&={\bigl (}{\begin{smallmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{smallmatrix}}{\bigr )},&r_{1}&={\bigl (}{\begin{smallmatrix}0&-1\\1&0\end{smallmatrix}}{\bigr )},&r_{2}&={\bigl (}{\begin{smallmatrix}-1&0\\0&-1\end{smallmatrix}}{\bigr )},&r_{3}&={\bigl (}{\begin{smallmatrix}0&1\\-1&0\end{smallmatrix}}{\bigr )},\\s_{0}&={\bigl (}{\begin{smallmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{smallmatrix}}{\bigr )},&s_{1}&={\bigl (}{\begin{smallmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{smallmatrix}}{\bigr )},&s_{2}&={\bigl (}{\begin{smallmatrix}-1&0\\0&1\end{smallmatrix}}{\bigr )},&s_{3}&={\bigl (}{\begin{smallmatrix}0&-1\\-1&0\end{smallmatrix}}{\bigr )}.\end{aligned}

These eight matrices are computed by inserting multiples of $\frac{\pi}{2}$ in the above formulae for $n$-gon, and they are **representative** of the eight group operations.
In two-dimensional space $R^2$, linear maps are generally described by 2 × 2 matrices, and above eight matrices are the eight mappings you are looking for. And you are thus quite right argueing that *any action of D4 is a combination of rotations and reflections and hence linear*.

---

What basis to choose?
Note: The set **R**$^2$ of the ordered pairs of real numbers is a vector space under the operations of component-wise addition and scalar multiplication; that is

$(a,b)+(c,d)=(a+c,b+d)$
$\lambda (a,b)=(\lambda a,\lambda b)$,
where $\lambda$ is any real number.

A simple basis of this vector space consists of the two vectors $e_1 = (1, 0)$ and $e_2 = (0, 1)$.
These vectors form a basis (called the standard basis) because any vector $v = (a, b)$ of **R**$^2$ may be uniquely written as
$\displaystyle {v} =a {e}_{1}+b {e}_{2}$.
However, **any** other pair of **linearly independent** vectors of **R**$^2$, such as $(1, 1)$ and $(−1, 2)$, forms a basis of **R**$^2$ as well. So long as you choose a pair of linearly independent vectors, you're good to go.

---

As for their traces:
The trace of a square matrix $A$, denoted $tr(A)$, is defined to be the sum of elements on the main diagonal (from the upper left to the lower right) of A.
In your example, $tr(r_0)=2$, $tr(r_2)=-2$, and all other traces are $0$.

Comment: okay, but what is the representation, and how do we calculate the trace of it?

Comment: I see, thanks (+1)!